# How to randomly select a certain percent of rows in Access with another condition?

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

I have a table with, let's say, boys, girls, number of purchases and price. I want to randomly select 10%  of girls with a condition that money they  spent should be 30% of a total amount of money spent from both groups. To select 10% of girls I use this code:

`SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT from Students 
Where StudentType='girl'
ORDER BY rnd(ID)`

How should I place an additional condition?

Comment: The query doesn't actually select anything, the ORDER BY clause is in the wrong position and I suppose that girl is a string that should be delimited.  Please take care that the code you post is valid.  Did you mean `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM Students WHERE StudentType='girl' ORDER BY rnd(ID)'?

Comment: Yes, I made amendments, sorry.

Comment: Even though you changed part of the query, the query is still not selecting anything.  You have no fields to return.  Have you actually tried running the query that you post, because it would not work as you have it typed?  Notice that I included `*` in my statement which indicates return all fields in Students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already selecting a random portion, the question is really just about selection criteria involving a "total".  The key here is that you need another query, an aggregate query.  The other query can be either another saved query, an embedded subquery, or a call to a function which performs the query.

**Using a subquery to get the total**:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * 
FROM Students 
WHERE StudentType='girl' 
    AND (Students.[Spent] / (SELECT SUM(S2.[Spent]) FROM Students As S2) = 0.30)
ORDER BY rnd(ID)
```

Make sure to add a different alias to the same table, since Access can get confused if the subquery has a table with the same name as the main query.  The question did not mention the "amount spent" column so I just guessed.  This also assumes that "both groups" is essentially the same as "all student records".  If that's not the case then you could add to the subquery `WHERE S2.StudentType In ('girl', 'boy')`.

**Using a domain aggregate function**:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * 
FROM Students 
WHERE StudentType='girl' 
    AND (Students.[Spent] / DSum("[Spent]", "Students", "") = 0.30)
ORDER BY rnd(ID)
```

**Using another saved query**:

First create and save the separate aggregate query as [Summed]:

```
SELECT SUM(S2.[Spent]) As TotalSpent FROM Students As S2
```

Now do a cross join so that each row is paired with the total:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * 
FROM Students, Summed
WHERE StudentType='girl' 
    AND (Students.[Spent] / Summed.TotalSpent = 0.30)
ORDER BY rnd(ID)
```

The efficiency of each solution may vary.  For a small table of students it might not matter. If it does become an issue, I have found that the Domain Aggregate functions are not very efficient even though they appear to be simpler to use. More powerful query engines (not Access) are often better at analyzing a query plan and automatically reducing redundant calculations, but with Access you have to plan that out yourself.

Last note: If you have more complicated grouping, any of the solutions will have additional join conditions.  For instance, if the aggregate query also had a GROUP BY clause on an ID, then instead of a cross join, you'd now want an INNER JOIN matching the ID in the main table.  In the case of the domain aggregate function, you'd want to specify a *criteria* parameter that refers to a table field value.  The point is that the above examples are not a precise template for all cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer! But it seems like I cant understand how sum is calculated for the selected 'girls' ( I mean the numerator Students.[Spent] ). So, we take one girl, we know how much she spent, we take another girl and then we need to calculate their common spent value and then divide that value by total sum spent of all students.

Comment: First of all, `Students.[Spent]` was only an example field.  You did not tell us in your question the name of your fields, so I simply imagined an example field name... [Spent].  Unless you give exact detail on Stack Overflow questions, many answers will include such example details.

Comment: You must realize that I can only interpret your question literally.  You say "total sum spent of all students".  That is exactly what each of the queries do.  The key word is **sum**.  All three techniques I outlined get the total (i.e. sum) of the [Spent] field in ALL rows in the Students table.

Comment: Back to interpreting what you say... What do you mean by "we take another girl and then we need to calculate their common spent value"?  That is different than your original question. I don't know what you are implying by "_common_ spent value".  I'm also not sure what you mean by "take another girl". The examples I gave you will take _each row separately that has StudentType='girl'_ and then for each separate row (i.e. "girl") take the single [Spent] value and divide it by the total (as described in previous comment). It then applies the condition that is should 30% of total (`= 0.30`).

Comment: If you want something different, they you need to explain in precise terms... or experiment yourself.  For instance, if instead of "ALL students" you mean only all girls (and not boys), then each of the summation queries also needs to have `WHERE StudentType='girls'`.  Of if you mean that you want the total spent of the random 10% to be 30% of total, then you need two aggregate queries.  But then I would begin to question if you really understand that might never give you anything. Also, picking only an exact 30% might never return anything... do you instead mean a range of values like < 30%?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you - I shouldn't ve told about price and number of purchases, I should've said only about [Spent] field, because we simply can calculate it by multiplying price and number of purchases.
Yes, your query check condition for each _italic_ SEPARATE row

Comment: Okay, I hope you get it working.  It is difficult to express everything in short comments.  No need to be sorry about the confusion and I also don't mean any offense, I am just being specific so that you can learn how to post improved details in the future.  I see that you are newer to posting on Stack Overflow, and the culture can be difficult to get into.  Others here are not even as patient as I am... they'll just mark down the question without any help if they get confused.

Comment: I lost connection to the internet, so there is a second part of my comment.

Comment: _Yes, your query check condition for each italic SEPARATE row_.


I mean another logic- I want to pick up girls, so that their _TOTAL_ sum([Spent]) equals 30%. 
Of course, I don't want to select exactly 30% ( it will  never happen in a real data set), I want approximately 30%. I think, I will try it in a VBA and post it here.